# How cast type int with atoi() to Int32

Tags: c, casting, atoi, int32

I've got a piece of C code:

```
Int32 tmp = atoi("314");
```

It throws an error:

```
error: Int32 undeclared (first use in this function)
```

I have no idea why? Could you help me?

Maybe it is problem with `#include`s:

- `sys/socket.h`
- `netinet/in.h`
- `arpa/inet.h`
- `stdio.h`
- `stdlib.h`
- `string.h`
- `strings.h`

Comment: i think you want `int tmp = atoi("314");`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no standard type called `Int32`. You're probably looking for

```
int tmp = atoi("314");
```

If you need a 32-bit integer, the standard type is `int32_t` defined in `inttypes.h` or `stdint.h`.

Comment: Also note that `atoi` is not useful if your goal is to ensure that the 32-bit numbers can be read (`int` could be smaller than 32 bit). In that case you'd need `strtol` or `sscanf` with the `SCNd32` macro from `inttypes.h`.

Answer (score 2):

There is no built-in `Int32` type in C. You can include [`stdint.h`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/stdint.h.html) for `int32_t` and `uint32_t` though. But in this case, you probably want to use `int`.

```
int tmp = atoi("314");
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want Int32 variable you should use

```
<arm.h>
```

Check this link. http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009619299/apdxa.htm

Comment: *Really*? Why would you want to include that random header? And also, that defines `int32`, not `Int32`.

Comment: Err... shouldn't he just include `stdint.h` instead of some random possibly platform-specific header.